# array de arrays count_values php

Tags: php

Como puedo aplicar la funcion array_count_values() a un array de arrays.

Ejemplo:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [91] => 123 [94] => 123 ) [2] => Array ( [91] => 10 [94] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [91] => 02 [94] => 1 )
```

Quiero obtener que para [1], 123 se repite dos veces.

Comment: Hola DanielGB. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora? Has de mostrar lo intentado y qué errores o problemas has tenido. Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habría que iterar por cada elemento de matriz con, por ejemplo, un `foreach`:

```
<?php
/* Matriz de ejemplo tomado de la pregunta */
$matriz = [
  1 => [
    91 => 123,
    94 => 123,
  ],
  2 => [
    91 => 10,
    94 => 13,
  ],
  3 => [
    91 => 02,
    94 => 1,
  ]
];
/* Creamos una matriz vacía para almacenar el resultado */ 
$resultado = [];
/* Iteramos por cada elemento de la matriz inicial */
foreach ($matriz as $clave => $valor) {
  /* Almacenamos en la matriz de salida el resultado de contar elementos */
  $resultado[$clave] = array_count_values($valor);
}
/* Mostramos el resultado */
var_export($resultado);
```

El resultado de la ejecución será:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    123 => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    10 => 1,
    13 => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    2 => 1,
    1 => 1,
  ),
)
```